# Sort by length attribute of a class which is stored as List in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

data is an array containing a class likes List I want to filter according to the length of this list, but the filtering is not working. Can you help me? I left the code I tried below.

`data .map((e) => e.likes.length) .toList() .sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code

```
var sortedList = data.toList()..sort((a, b) => a.likes.length.compareTo(b.likes.length));
```

Example:

```
class Post {
  List<String> likes;
  Post({required this.likes});
}

void main() {
  List<Post> posts = [
    Post(likes: ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']),
    Post(likes: ['user4', 'user5']),
    Post(likes: ['user6', 'user7', 'user8', 'user9']),
    Post(likes: ['user10']),
  ];
  posts.sort((a, b) => a.likes.length.compareTo(b.likes.length));

  posts.forEach((post) => print(post.likes));
}
```

Output:

```
[user10]
[user4, user5]
[user1, user2, user3]
[user6, user7, user8, user9]
```

**Edit: For vice versa**

Use the following:

```
posts.sort((a, b) => b.likes.length.compareTo(a.likes.length));
```

Output:

```
[user6, user7, user8, user9]
[user1, user2, user3]
[user4, user5]
[user10]
```